# AJAX code clarification

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am messing around with Jquery AJAX couple of day's and on the net i found this code below:
I know what this code does but i am having trouble ***understanding*** some parts of it. For example I don't know what **(url)** is. I know it is a function parameter but don't know what it represent or contains. I also don't understand what is **responseText** inside this function. So i am hoping that someone can explain those parameters to me. Sorry for the noob question! And thank you!!

```
example_ajax_request(url) {

$('#example-placeholder').load(url, "",
    function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        if(textStatus == 'error') {
            $('#example-placeholder').html('<p>There was an error making the AJAX request</p>');
        }
    }
);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/load

`url` is the url that you are loading content from, and `responseText` contains the text content that was returned from the ajax request. You do not need to do anything with `responseText` because it is automatically being set as the content of the `#example-placeholder` element.

Answer (score 1):

url is the url to wich the request is being sent. responseText holds the server's response.
In your example, the url is a var that must have been set before. A string could also be passed to the function, like `'http://example.url'` The responseText var will be set once the request returns from the server and will hold any data rendered by the server.